# How to get items from Anonymous access List

Tags: 2010

I would like to enable anonymous access only one list in my sitecollection to display news on login page of form base authentication.In order to do that I have enable Anonymous access at web application level and at sitecollection level i enable anonymous access to List and Libraries.
I have News list at root level and i broke permisson here to allow anonymous access for view items.

Now i am trying to access this list in UserControl but getting error saying List does not exists but same code work in Console application.

i am getting error at this line  SPList News = web.Lists["News"];

Please advise how i can programatically get items from Anonymous access list.

Thanks 
ROnak

Comment: If you hit the site as an anonymous user and go directly to the list, can you see the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dave for your reply i actually had figure it out and what i did is instead of breaking permission on list programatically i did manually and it worked so something wrong in my code.Thanks